# SQL Pairing rows with cross value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pair two rows in a table.

```
ZZ  XX  PZZ  PXX 
A   B    1    2
G   E    5    9
M   N    4    4
E   H    7    4
Q   R    2    2
T   D    8    1
H   E    4    7
B   A    2    1
L   B    7    3
```

I want to pair the row with has same value but the values cross into other column like following.
Expected output :

```
ZZ  XX  PZZ  PXX
A   B   1    2
B   A   2    1
E   H   7    4
H   E   4    7
```

Comment: Neat - did you have a question?

Comment: yes, I have edited my question.

Comment: I still see no question...  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?  Please also show what attempts you have made to solve your problem.  We are not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `INNER JOIN` will do:

```
SELECT t1.ZZ, t1.XX, t1.PZZ, t1.PXX
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 
ON t1.ZZ = t2.XX AND t1.XX = t2.ZZ AND t1.PZZ = t2.PXX AND t1.PXX = t2.PZZ
```

The `ON` clause does a cross-matching between `XX`, `ZZ` and between `PXX`, `PZZ` columns f the table.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b51bf5/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use an EXISTS clause to check if a sibling exists.

```
select *
from mytable
where exists
(
  select *
  from mytable pair
  where pair.zz = mytable.xx
    and pair.xx = mytable.zz
    and pair.pzz = mytable.pxx
    and pair.pxx = mytable.pzz
);
```

Or even simpler with an IN clause:

```
select *
from mytable
where (zz, xx, pzz, pxx) in
(
  select xx, zz, pxx, pzz
  from mytable
);
```

If you want your results sorted, use ORDER BY with LEAST and GREATEST:

```
order by least(xx, zz), greatest(xx, zz), zz, least(pxx, pzz), greatest(pxx, pzz), pzz;
```